# Python Random choice result in discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

how to make below code work in discord channel. the output should be in discord channel when used command.

```
colours = {'red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'black', 'purple',
           'Brown', 'Orange', 'violet', 'gray'}
for n in [5]:
    cs = random.sample(colours, k=n)
    colours -= set(cs)
    print(cs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)  
async def pick(ctx):
  colours_copy = colours.copy()
  for n in [1, 2, 3]:
      cs = random.sample(colours_copy , k=n)
      colours_copy -= set(cs)
      await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "{}\n".format(", ".join(cs)))
```

If you were to subtract the set from colours every time someone ran `!pick` you would run out of colours pretty quickly

Instead, you can make a copy of your set inside the function so that even when you subtract from it during its execution, the original set will always be there as a reference

*"the output should be in discord channel when used command !choose"*
You can change what the command name is (it's currently `pick`)

Comment: Replace it with ` await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "Line {} >{}\n".format(str(n),", ".join(cs)))`

Comment: So instead of "Line 1" you add a custom message?  
Depends on what you want to add

Comment: There's couple of ways you could do this, you can have an array of 3 people and every time it prints the colours use `pop()` to remove the last one from the array

Comment: You add an array of people `people = ["Jake","Suzan","Kyle"]` and edit the bot.say command `await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "{} - {}\n".format(people.pop(),", ".join(cs)))`

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish, try posting a new detailed question with your code and errors so far

Comment: `await client.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "{}\n".format(f" Line {n} > " + ", ".join(cs)))`

Comment: Above `for n in [1, 2, 3]:` put `counter =0 ` and below it put `counter += 1` and instead of {n} in the last thing I wrote, put {counter}

Comment: Is possible to add weights for some words in `colours list`

Comment: I have no idea, never worked with weights, try posting another question thread

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.content.upper() == ".CHOOSE":

            # Your code here

            await client.send_message(message.channel, "> {}\n".format(", ".join(cs)))
```

Should have the bot send the output just how it looks in the console to the respective channel the command is used in.